# Pre-populate form, from multiple models, for the purpose of "update"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm rather new to Django, so please forgive the rather newbish question I need to ask. Basically, I have a problem I'm having great difficulty implementing after countless searches.

What I would like to do, is create an input form in a page, and populate it with data from the database. I would then like to be able to click on a button to update whatever changes I make to the form. The catch here is that the form will take data from two models, a main model, and a submodel related to it. Exactly like how an Invoice might have multiple items within it.

The furthest I've gotten was displaying the main model but not the submodel, or displaying everything, but the button not doing anything. Here are the code:

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class InvoiceList(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    recipient = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    issue_date = models.DateField()
    deadline = models.DateField()
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.recipient

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tax = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    list = models.ForeignKey(InvoiceList)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_description + " (" + str(self.list) + ")"
```

forms.py **(EDITED)** (added "can_delete+=False" to prevent appearance of "Delete" checkbox. Checkbox needs to be checked in order for "is_valid" to flag as True... which is nonsense. So remove that!)

```
import datetime
from bill.models import *
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

class InvoiceListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceList
        fields = ['invoice_number', 'recipient', 'issue_date', 'deadline', 'additional_info']

class InvoiceItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        exclude = ('list',)
        fields = ['item_description', 'number', 'price', 'tax']

InvoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(InvoiceList, InvoiceItem, fields=('id','item_description','number','price','tax',), extra=0, can_delete=False)
```

Partial view of views.py **(EDITED)** (Probably can be cleaned heavily, but here's the engine to make it update!)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory, BaseFormSet
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from bill.forms import *
from .forms import InvoiceFormSet
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.template import RequestContext

def update_edit(request, invoice_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(InvoiceList, pk=invoice_id)
    b = InvoiceFormSet(instance=a, prefix="item")
    c = InvoiceListForm(instance=a, prefix="list")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        gaga = InvoiceListForm(request.POST, instance=a, prefix="list")
        lala = InvoiceFormSet(request.POST, instance=a, prefix="items")
        if gaga.is_valid() and lala.is_valid():
            gaga.save()
            lala.save()
            return HttpResponse('Good, saved the thing!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('No shway! Didn't save cos not valid!')
    else:
        c = InvoiceListForm(instance=a, prefix="list")
        b = InvoiceFormSet(instance=a, prefix="items")

    d = {'invoice_info': c, 'items': b}
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'bill/update.html', {'form': invoice_info, 'items': invoice_stuff})
```

Here's the frontend update.html **(EDITED)** (Added management thing)

```
<h1>Updating Invoice</h1>

<form action="." name="stock_details" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<hr>
{{ form.as_p }}
{{ items.management_form }}
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

<hr>

<input type='submit' value='Update'/>
</form>
```

<del>I would put in {{ item.as_p }}, but that doesn't display anything unfortunately. I'm not sure why. The above displays all of the data. The exception are the items, they don't appear inside an input tag... I'll have to do that manually I suppose.</del>

<del>EDIT - I've modified the code to show both the invoice and its child items into the formset, which displays well and has content populated. I'm trying to figure out how to save the form at this point, assuming there are changes. Help?</del>

All solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your intention is with that code because of all the comments. One thing that is clear though is that your `{% for item in detail.invoiceitem_set.all %}` is not resulting in form inputs because you're not looping through fields in the form there, you're looping through items in a queryset.

Comment: Thanks for responding ChidG! I've edited out most of the comments (except one). So do you have a suggestion on how I can achieve displaying {{ item.as_p }}?

Comment: It looks like your intention is to produce an inline form for each item, where you can edit the number, price etc of the item - is that the case? If so, you should look into Django's inline model formsets.

Comment: Thank you @ChidG! I've finally narrowed down the formset issue thing, and have updated the code. Do you know what should be my next step towards saving the form? I tested it earlier, but it didn't save anything.

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. Saving inline formsets is very much like saving a form (`inlineformset_factory` is based on `modelformset_factory` so you can use all of its methods).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @ChidG! After tearing apart everything this afternoon, I finally solved the issue! One of the big problem I found was my use of an input button. Using that to access the update page somehow false-flagged POST as being true, causing havoc in the code... I was wondering why it kept skipping over displaying the page. Changing that to a simple text link left POST alone, allowing me to solve the update issue properly.

I'll update the code above in case anyone needs it in the future.

Comment: The input button wasn't the problem, it was the `method="post"` in the form element. You can change that to `method="get"` and then reinstate your input button.